# Warning: Unknown prop `on` on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

I Googled this warning, but I only see generic advices or hit about some other property. My relevant JSX:

```
<button className="btn btn-default edit-mode-button"
  onClick={this.onEditModeChange}>{editButtonLabel}</button>
```

As you can see I have `onClick`, but not `on`. But every example code I see use `onClick` as well. So what's the deal? How can I fix this?

---

Hmmm, looks like that the React I'm using is bumped from v 15.1.0 to v 15.5.7. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a space between `on` and `Click` by mistake?

Comment: I'm 100% sure  .

Comment: Can we see the whole error message? Have you made sure you're looking at the right file, element, etc?

Comment: @Li357 I put a breakpoint where that error message is triggered. It is 100% that the button above causes it, and during runtime the object does have an `on` property with a function assigned to it. I guess ReactJS transforms the `onClick` into that, I just don't know why this is a problem suddenly (it worked for almost a year fine)